# Creating a new list from an existing list with shifted index

Tags: python-3.x

The existing list is:

```
alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

If the input shift is 5 and the text input 'hello' we should find the index of 'h' and move along to 'm' and add that to a list so alphabet[h.index+shift]

I am currently trying the following:

```
for index, item in enumerate(alphabet, start=1):
            for letter in text:
                if letter == alphabet:
                    cipher_text.append(alphabet[index + shift])
```

But my list remains empty. Do I also need to enumerate the second loop or am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: you have two errors: `if letter==item` (not alphabet). the second is silent but if your text is `ahoy` you'll get an `IndexError`, because `index('y')+shift` will be superior to `len(alphabet)`. the modulo operator `%` will help you solve this. and you can save a loop by using the `index` method of lists: `alphabet.index('c')` returns `2`.

Comment: Thanks - have implemented that, seems much easier

Answer (score 0):

Solved using index:

```
cipher_text = ""
    for letter in plain_text:
        position = alphabet.index(letter)
        new_position = position + shift_amount
        new_letter = alphabet[new_position]
        cipher_text += new_letter
    print(f"The encoded text is {cipher_text}")
```